# Texture floating ponts - problem with rotation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have a texture in my Square. The problem is when I assign floating texture points the image gets rotated 45 degrees at right. I want it without the rotation.

The current texture points:

```
texture = new float[]{
0.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

This is how it ends:

[image]

This is how I want it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
texture = new float[]{
0.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

i.e. swapping the third and fourth entries.

Edit:
Should be:

```
texture = new float[]{
0.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

Comment: Could you post a picture of the problem?

Comment: Well, it worked, but I noticed that my texture now was flipped horizontally, any ideas? It was not flipped horizontally when it had been rotated?

Comment: Thank you, it works now. But (!) I'm not sure how to use the texture floats, how it is meant to be used. I understand the vertexs and indices floating points. It just the texture floating points that confuses me. Any resources where I can learn this?

Comment: The texture floating point values correspond to the coordinates of that vertex on the texture. with the first coordinate being the x coordinate (0.0 = left edge, 1.0 = right edge) and the second being vertical coordinate (0.0 = top edge, 1.0 = bottom edge), so 0.5,0.5 would be the centre of the texture image.

Answer (score 0):

This is OpenGL right? There could be several reasons... please post some code. Firstly are you sure your projection is set up correctly?

Secondly, check that your texture co-ords correctly correspond to your vertex coords.

Comment: The projection is correctly set up. When you say correspond to my vertex coords, how exactly do you mean?